# Query to get all siblings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like that:

```
 ID NAME SURNAME MotherID FatherID
    0   JJ   smi       NULL    NULL
    1   ja   rly       NULL    NUL
    2   ak   smi       0        1
    3   ol   smi       0        1
    4   oa   woo       2        3
    5   oe   boo       2        3

    etc.
```

I need query that with specific parameter as NAME and surname will return me all siblings of a person.
Expected output

```
NAME SURNAME FATHERNAME FATHERSURNAME MOTHERNAME MOTHERSURNAME
AK   SMI        JA        RLY             JJ        SMI        
OL   SMI        JA        RLY             JJ        SMI
```

I tried

```
SELECT 
      a.name,
      a.surname 
FROM PEOPLE a, PEOPLE b
WHERE (b.name = 'ak' AND b.surname ='smi' AND 
      (b.motherID = a.ID OR b.fatherid = ID))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes i tired to create cte but I don't think its the right way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: Siblings belongs to the same generation. Use a self join.

Comment: I strongly suggest you start learning the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax, it's been around for 28 years now, and has long superceded the 31 year old ANSI-89 JOIN syntax you're using.

Comment: Added my try with self join but it doesnt return anything

Comment: How do you define "sibling"?  For instance, does it require that both parents match or is one sufficient?  In addition, in many countries, a child can (legally) have two parents of the same sex/gender.  How is that represented?

Comment: @GordonLinoff One same parent is enough to qualify for sibiling. Sex of parents doesnt matter for that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **SUB QUERY** to achieve this.

Table Creation:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
ID INT,
NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
SURNAME VARCHAR(MAX),
MOTHERID INT,
FATHERID INT)
```

Table Insertion:

```
Insert into @t Values(0,'JJ','smi',NULL,NULL)
Insert into @t Values(1,'ja','rly',NULL,NULl)
Insert into @t Values(2,'ak','smi',0,1)
Insert into @t Values(3,'ol','smi',0,1)
Insert into @t Values(4,'oa','woo',2,3)
Insert into @t Values(5,'oe','boo',2,3)
```

Query:

```
SELECT S.NAME AS NAME,S.SURNAME AS SURNAME,S.FATHER_NAME ,S.FATHER_SURNAME,M.NAME AS 
MOTHER_NAME,M.SURNAME AS MOTHER_SURNAME 
FROM @T M INNER JOIN(
SELECT T2.NAME AS NAME,T2.SURNAME AS SURNAME,T1.NAME AS FATHER_NAME,T1.SURNAME AS 
FATHER_SURNAME,T2.MOTHERID
FROM @T T1
INNER JOIN @T T2 ON  T1.ID=T2.FATHERID 
WHERE T2.NAME IN ('AK','OL'))S ON M.ID=S.MOTHERID
```

Output:

[image]
Also ,add the **WHERE** clause based on your parameter requirement.

Comment: Share your comments whether this query works for your case or not -- @uberxeq

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way you can get it. From here you can explore a few other options!

```
CREATE PROC GetSiblings
(
    @GivenName AS VARCHAR(100),
    @SurName AS VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        A.GivenName,
        A.SurName,
        F.GivenName AS FatherGivenName,
        F.SurName AS FatherSurName,
        M.GivenName AS MotherGivenName,
        M.SurName AS MotherSurName,
    FROM PEOPLE AS P INNER JOIN PEOPLE AS F ON P.FatherID = F.ID
        INNER JOIN PEOPLE AS M ON P.MotherID = M.ID
    WHERE P.GivenName = @GivenName AND P.SurName = @SurName
    UNION --By father
    SELECT 
        A.GivenName,
        A.SurName,
        F.GivenName AS FatherGivenName,
        F.SurName AS FatherSurName,
        M.GivenName AS MotherGivenName,
        M.SurName AS MotherSurName,
    FROM PEOPLE AS P INNER JOIN PEOPLE AS F ON P.FatherID = F.ID
        INNER JOIN PEOPLE AS M ON P.MotherID = M.ID
    WHERE P.FatherID IN (SELECT DISTINCT FatherID FROM PEOPLE WHERE GivenName = @GivenName AND SurName = @SurName)
    UNION --By mother
    SELECT 
        A.GivenName,
        A.SurName,
        F.GivenName AS FatherGivenName,
        F.SurName AS FatherSurName,
        M.GivenName AS MotherGivenName,
        M.SurName AS MotherSurName,
    FROM PEOPLE AS P INNER JOIN PEOPLE AS F ON P.FatherID = F.ID
        INNER JOIN PEOPLE AS M ON P.MotherID = M.ID
    WHERE P.MotherID IN (SELECT DISTINCT MotherID FROM PEOPLE WHERE GivenName = @GivenName AND SurName = @SurName);
END;
```